# itemChanged never called on QGraphicsItem

Tags: qt, qt4

In this example:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/Qt/InteractwithQGraphicsItem.htm

the itemChange() function is where all of the updating work takes place. However, this function doesn't seem to be called when I move the handles around. According to:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#itemChange

it should be called whenever the state changes, which I would imagine would include the position. Can anyone explain how to make this function get called when the handles are moved?

Comment: All that was missing was a setFlag(ItemSendsGeometryChanges);. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemChange-enum) check the `QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionChange`:

> The item's position changes. This notification is sent if the
>   `ItemSendsGeometryChanges` flag is enabled, and when the item's local
>   position changes, relative to its parent (i.e., as a result of calling
>   `setPos()` or `moveBy()`). The value argument is the new position (i.e., a
>   `QPointF`). You can call `pos()` to get the original position. **Do not call
>   `setPos()` or `moveBy()` in `itemChange()` as this notification is
>   delivered;** instead, you can return the new, adjusted position from
>   `itemChange()`. After this notification, `QGraphicsItem` immediately sends
>   the `ItemPositionHasChanged` notification if the position changed.

So you should enable the flag `QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges` in order to have the `itemChange` called when the position changes.

By default this is [disabled for optimization](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum):

> **For performance reasons, these notifications are disabled by default.
>   You must enable this flag to receive notifications for position and
>   transform changes.** This flag was introduced in Qt 4.6.

In order to set a flag you should call the [`setFlag`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#setFlag) function preferably in the constructor of your custom item.

```
item->setFlag(GraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
```

Comment: webclectic - you are right. I have a new problem - http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/Qt/Utilities/HandleItem I am trying to make the right edge of the rectangle follow the right handle. However, the handle seems to move faster than the rectangle. I have added a bunch of debug outputs and everything seems to look correct, but the result is wrong! Any suggestions?

Comment: It turns out if you change point.setX( m_item->boundingRect().right() );

to

point.setX( m_item->boundingRect().right() - pos().x() );

in boundingRect it works correctly. What I think it says is "set the x coordinate of the corner of the handle to the right edge of the rectangle - the location of the handle" right? I don't
understand that - shouldn't the the x coordinate of the corner of the handle just be equal to the position of the handle?? Why does boundingRect have to be implemented at all?